# Chown NFS Volume Nobody for user Nobody for group

Tags: nfs, rhel, chown

Everytime I try to chown a file from root it will be nobody:nobody on the nfs server. It's working as root but it's not working with anything else. I'm on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4.

I use these settings in /etc/exports 
(This server is on internal network only)
/storage *(rw,async,no_all_squash,no_root_squash,anonuid=99,anongid=99)

Can you help me? I alredy spend a complete day to try fix it.

Best Wishes,
Thomas

Comment: on /etc/export use `(fsid=1,rw,sync,all_squash,anonuid=99,anongid=99)` and mount the filesystem like `mount.nfs -o resvport`